# Selecting columns of a set of boolean matrices with constraint on the ones in each row

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices

I've come up with the following question in my research: Let $S$ be a finite set of $n \times n$ matrices with elements 0 or 1. denote $n_i$ as the total number of 1's in the $i$th row of all matrices in $S$. We want to select one column of each matrix, such that for the $i$th row, at least $\lfloor \frac{\alpha n_i}{n} \rfloor $  of the ones in that row are selected. Is there any $\alpha>0$ that we can guarantee the existence of such selection? In particular, what is the maximum $\alpha$ that we can guarantee?
Is there a previous well known result about this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the problem wasn't explained correctly. I've edited my question.

Comment: And yes, S is finite and all the matrices are $n \times n$

Comment: It seems that the question is about $\alpha_0$, which equals the maximal $\alpha$ that we can guarantee and $1/|S|\le \alpha_0\le 1 $, because if $0<\alpha<1/|S|$  then the condition is trivially satisfied because $\lfloor \frac{\alpha n_i}{n} \rfloor=0$.

Comment: In fact, I'm looking for constant $\alpha$, independent of $|S|$ or $n$.

Comment: It's natural. Now I'm trying to check these $\alpha$'s, in particular, $\alpha=1$.

Comment: $\alpha$ is strictly less than one. As an example, consider these two $4 \times 4$ matrices:  
$$
1 1 0 0    \mbox{   --       }     0 1 0 1  
$$
$$
1 1 0 0    \mbox{   --       }     1 0 1 0  
$$
$$
0 0 1 1    \mbox{ --         }     1 0 1 0  
$$
$$
0 0 1 1    \mbox{   --       }     0 1 0 1  
$$
For any selection of columns, at least one row has no selected "1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturally generalizing your example we can show that $\alpha=0$. Consider the following construction. For any natural number $k$  put $n=2^k$ and consider matrices $A_1,\dots, A_k$, where each $A_j$ consists of $n/2$ copies of columns $a_j^T=(a_{ij})$, where $a_{ij}=1$, if $\lfloor i/2^{j-1} \rfloor$ is odd and $a_{ij}=0$, otherwise and $n/2$ copies of columns $(1,1,\dots, 1)^T- a_j^T $. Then $n_i=kn/2$  for each $i$, but for any selection of columns at least one row has no selected “1”.  So  $0=\lfloor \alpha n_i/n\rfloor=\lfloor \alpha k/2\rfloor$. That is $\alpha<2/k$.

Comment: Thanks, your construction shows that no constant $\alpha>0$ can be guaranteed. Do you think $\alpha = \Omega(\frac{1}{\log n})$?
Can I contact you by email, if necessary?

Comment: @Masood I have to think about this bound. Yes, you can contact me, my e-mail is oravsky@mail.ru

Comment: @Masood It seems that I can obtain a lower bound for $\alpha(n)$. To be continued...

Comment: @Masood I posted a [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335279/estimation-of-a-probability-of-marginal-values-of-a-random-variable) at MSE.

Comment: Thanks, I'll track it as well. Maybe searching for generalized form of probability bounds like chernoff helps.